# ANT delete task and Windows 7 UAC permissions

Tags: file-io, ant, windows-7, permissions, uac

When I do a simple delete of the contents of a folder,

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
  <fileset dir="${developmentenvironment.www.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
</delete>
```

I get an error:

```
C:\Users\...\build.xml:42: Unable to delete file C:\...\www\appserv\AUTHORS.txt
```

When, I try to delete the file in the OS, it requires elevated permissions.

I also can't get a UAC prompt by doing this:

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c del ./*.*"/>
</exec>
```

**Can ANT prompt for elevated UAC permissions when using the delete task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ant is designed to be a platform independent build system, I really doubt it provides this very windows-centric functionality. Can you  start your build task as a more appropriate user, for instance, one with permission to modify and delete the files needed to complete the build? Alternatively, can you add the user it is running as, recursively, to the permissions on the directory above the one you are trying to delete?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Ubuntu has an elevated permissions scheme as well. I could be wrong though. I think you are ultimately right though. I will have to run the build as an elevated user. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu just as 'sudo' hiding under a dialog box. No one would do software development in a tree that required sudo to write into it.

Answer (score 0):

Ant is just a Java program. No JRE will run it that I'm aware of can mess with UAC.